# A complicated integral inequality

Tags: fourier-analysis, integration

How can we bound this integral:

$${\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}2\left[\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4\left(1-\xi^{2}\right)}\left(1-\dfrac{\xi^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}\right]\left(\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)\right)^{2}e^{-2t}d\xi}
 $$

I've tried to use Holder inequality but when I compute $\left\Vert 2\left[\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4\left(1-\xi^{2}\right)}\left(1-\dfrac{\xi^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}\right]\right\Vert _{L_{\xi}^{2}\left(\left[-1,1\right]\right)}
 $, it is not defined since we have some kinds of $\log\left(\xi\pm1\right)
  $ in the anti-derivative.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $f$? Or, in other words, in whiuch terms do you want to estimate it? What is the sense of multiple $e^{-2t}$, which does not depend on $\xi$?

Comment: You can ignore $e^{-2t}$, just a constant

Comment: Actually I want to find an upper bound of the entire integral. It seems like Holder inequality does not work.

Comment: Or we can bound the function inside the integral before integrating it.

Comment: in general integral diverges at endpoints, you should assume something like ${\hat f}(\pm 1)=0$

Comment: Yes we can but that's not the main goal.

Comment: If $\hat{f}(\xi) = 1$, then your integral is $\infty$, which is then the only upper bound you can get. To answer the question, you need to be specific about assumptions on $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Well there is no assumptions on $\hat f$. I think we can bound the function $\left[\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4\left(1-\xi^{2}\right)}\left(1-\dfrac{\xi^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}\right] $ before integrating it.